# React problem while getting Laravel Passport access token

Tags: reactjs, axios, access-token, laravel-passport, refresh-token

I have a React app that's targeting PHP Laravel API. I've set up Passport authentication with expiring access and refresh tokens.

```
  public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addSeconds(10));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addHours(6));
        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(1));

    }
```

Access token is expiring in 10 sec for testing purposes obviously.

On the FE I've set up axios interceptors like this:

```
function AxiosInterceptor({ children }) {
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config) => {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).access_token}`
          : null;
        config.headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

        return config;
      },
      async (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    const refreshToken = async () => {
      try {
        const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).refresh_token
          : null;
        const token = await axios.post("/api/auth/refresh", {
          refresh_token: refresh_token,
        });
        
        ctxDispatch({ type: "USER_TOKEN", payload: token.data });
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token.data));
        return token;
      } catch (err) {
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    };

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      async (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response.status === 403 || error.response.status === 401) {
          if (!originalRequest._retry) {
            originalRequest._retry = true;
            const { data } = await refreshToken();               
            axios.defaults.headers.common[
              "Authorization"
            ] = `Bearer ${data.access_token}`;
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
            return axios(originalRequest);
          }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }, []);
  return children;
}

export default AxiosInterceptor;
```

AxiosInterceptor component wraps the root App Component in index.js and this works just fine when I'm trying to access a protected endpoint with the expired access token, BUT at the same time the FE route ie. screen in React doesn't change. When the screen changes on the FE and then I try to access another protected endpoint in that component's useEffect hook that API call most likely gets called before AxiosInterceptor does its thing and I get an error response from the backend. Then when the refresh token function gets called I don't have a valid refresh token in localStorage and I get an invalid refresh token as a response.

A little extra context before this I had all the AxiosInterceptor code in the body of the App component. When I put it in the new AxiosInterceptor component and wrap the App component with it actually worked a few times but most of the time I get an invalid ref token as a response

I tried putting a rendering condition in AxiosInterceptor so that it renders its children only when the refresh token is there.

```
function AxiosInterceptor({ children }) {
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
  
///The Same axios interceptors code

    if (ref_token) setIsDone(true);
  }, []);
  return isDone && children;
}

export default AxiosInterceptor;
```

This however doesn't help and it only makes the whole App not render completely when there's no refresh token.